# Relay Nest T-Stat

Tags: electrical, heating

Can I use a nest T-Stat T3007ES to run 2, 2ooo watt cadet in wall heaters model RMC202W if I use a relay, and if so, what is the proper relay to use?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. If an answer is helpful, please click the large check mark next to it to accept. And, props for [taking our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) before posting; few newbies do.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to use both a transformer and relays.  Some relays have built-in transformers, but the transformers don't necessarily have the "oomph" to run both the relay and the Nest.

Transformers are about $13 and come in a variety of form-factors.  Relays also.   In most such installations you will have freedom as to where to put the Nest; it doesn't have to be at the 240V 'stat location.

The best place to site these components is at the heater, since there's lots of room in a heater.  The alternate is an unimproved basement or near the service panel.

How that's arranged is a function of how the wiring is laid out.  Add a wiring diagram of your setup and we can advise further.

Comment: I'm curious - do you have an example of a relay with a built-in transformer?  That sound useful.